# Annotation Right Accessory Button won't change

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

My annotations trigger the right actions, but they aren't showing the right accessory button no matter which button I choose. Below is my code.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{

    static NSString *s = @"ann";
    MKAnnotationView *pin = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:s];
    if (annotation != self.mapView.userLocation) {
        pin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:s];
        pin.canShowCallout = YES;

        pin.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);

        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        pin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button;
        [button addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(getDirections:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    return pin;
}
```

Comment: try changing MKAnnotationView to MKPinAnnotationView above your if

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "annotations trigger the right actions"?  **Is the map view's delegate set?**  Did you confirm that your viewForAnnotation delegate method is actually getting called (put a breakpoint in it)?

Comment: user22.. That gives me the error: Incompatible pointer types initializing 'MKPinAnnotationView *' with an expression of type 'MKAnnotationView *'. @Anna I just meant that tapping on the annotation has an action, and the action works. The delegate method is getting called.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{
        // If it's the user location, just return nil.
        if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
            return nil;

        // Handle any custom annotations.
        MKAnnotationView *pin = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"ann"];
        if(pin){
        pin.annotation = annotation;
    } else {
        pin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"ann"];
    }

    pin.canShowCallout = YES;
    pin.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    pin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button;
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(getDirections:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return pin;
}
```

Comment: the line 'pin = annotation' gives me the following warning: Assigning to 'MKAnnotationView *_strong' from incompatible type '_strong id<MKAnnotation>'

Comment: sorry i made i mistake, it should be pin.annotation = annotation;

Comment: Unfortunately I still don't see the button.

Comment: Side note here: you don't need to add the action to the button you're creating.  "If the view you specify is also a descendant of the `UIControl` class, you can use the map view’s delegate to receive notifications when your control is tapped. If it does not descend from `UIControl`, your view is responsible for handling any touch events within its bounds." See `-[MKMapViewDelegate mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:]`.